# How merge or join two dataframes, but keeping certain columns of both

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

How merge or join two dataframes, but keeping certain columns of both?

I need to merge this two dataframes into one. dataframe 2 has all the columns dataframe 1 just need the column "leads"

Dataframe1

```
campaignid leads 
35119190 391 
31664745 365 
4899110 211 
325772660 195 
64002140 131 
143679198 58 
283494007 45
```

Dataframe2

```
campaignid cost time reach 
35119190 391 391 391 
31664745 365 391 391 
4899110 211 391 391 
325772660 195 391 391 
64002140 131 391 391 
143679198 58 391 391 
283494007 45 391 391
```

**Desired result:**

Dataframe2

```
campaignid cost time reach leads 
35119190 391 391 391 391 
31664745 365 391 391 365 
4899110 211 391 391 211 
325772660 195 391 391 195 
64002140 131 391 391 131 
143679198 58 391 391 58 
283494007 45 391 391 45
```

g_spend.to_dict()

```
{'id': {0: 35119190,
  1: 64002140,
  2: 272351300,
  3: 4899110,},
 'Campaign_ID_name': {0: 'brand',
  1: '-',
  2: '-',
  3: 'science',
,
 'Month': {0: '2019|08',
  1: '2019|08',
  2: '2019|08',
  3: '2019|08',
},
 'Account': {0: 'a',
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'c',
},
 'campaignid': {0: 35119190,
  1: 64002140,
  2: 272351300,
  3: 4899110,
 },
 'campaign_name': {0: 'All_Brand',
  1: 'All',
  2: 'All_GBHS',
  3: 'All_Science',
},
 'cost': {0: '$59,399.37 ',
  1: '$12,660.37 ',
  2: '$5,631.96 ',
}}
```

grouped_cw.to_dict()

```
{'leads': {'1076533154': 40.0,
  '143679198': 58.0,
  '169278078': 13.0,
  '1729099155': 8.0,
}}
```

Comment: isn't it just `Dataframe1.merge(Dataframe2, on='campaignid')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang unfortunately not, I tried before. it give error: "You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
"

Comment: That says the two campaignid are not of the same type. Convert them both to string?

Comment: thanks @Quang Hoang, but it still not working. KeyError: 'campaignid' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: –  
I used grouped_cw= cw.groupby(["campaignid"]).sum() in one of the dataframes, it mid be the cause of issue

Comment: df1.to_dict() and df2.to_dict() add the outputs of those to this question.

Comment: @ScottBoston ,   so I transformed to a dic,     g_spend = g_spend.to_dict()        AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: @ScottBoston I uptated, here is the output from the dictionaries

Comment: Ah... grouped_cw id is a series with campaignids in the index!

Comment: @ScottBoston, what is your suggestion for fix that, could I use a for loop to count. because actually what I need is the count of lead. 

 I believe this is the problem 

 ``` 
grouped_cw= cw.groupby(["campaignid"]).sum()`
``

so maybe
```
a= [ ]
count=0

for i in cw["campaignid"]:
   i=a
   if a==a
   count+= 1
```

Do you think would work?

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.merge(Dataframe1, Dataframe2, on='campaignid')
```

Comment: unfortunately not, I tried before. it give error: "You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat "

Comment: @Peter : You are trying to merge on two different types of data then. Check the datatypes.One is probably a string, one is an Int.

Comment: thanks @GSBYBF, but it still not working. KeyError: 'campaignid' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: – 
I used grouped_cw= cw.groupby(["campaignid"]).sum() in one of the dataframes, it mid be the cause of issue

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `map`:

```
df2['leads'] = df2['campaignid'].map(df1.set_index('campaignid')['leads'])
df2
```

Output:

```
   campaignid  cost  time  reach  leads
0    35119190   391   391    391    391
1    31664745   365   391    391    365
2     4899110   211   391    391    211
3   325772660   195   391    391    195
4    64002140   131   391    391    131
5   143679198    58   391    391     58
6   283494007    45   391    391     45
```

Try

```
df2['leads'] = df2['campaignid'].map(grouped_cw)
```

Comment: thanks @Scott Boston, but it still not working. KeyError: 'campaignid'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: I used ```grouped_cw= cw.groupby(["campaignid"]).sum()``` in one of the dataframes, it mid be the cause of issue